# Dart - For loop is changing elements of my list even when it is cloned

Tags: flutter, dart

When I access to the elements of my list in a `for` loop, I would like to be able to modify them without impacting the original list.

Here's a simple example :

```
List pairs = [
  [1,8],
  [1,6],
];

print(pairs);

List copy = List.from(pairs);

for (List pair in copy) {
  if(pair.contains(1)) {
    pair.remove(1);
  }
}

print(pairs);
```

The output of this is :

```
[[1, 8], [1, 6]]
[[8], [6]]
```

I expected the output to be :

```
[[1, 8], [1, 6]]
[[1, 8], [1, 6]]
```

I tried to replace `List copy = List.from(pairs);` with :

```
List copy = [...pairs]; // This
List copy = []..addAll(pairs); // Or this
```

Nothing is working.

The only solution I found was to do this :

```
List temp = List.from(pair);
if(temp.contains(1)) {
  temp.remove(1);
}
```

But it seems to be a bit overkill. Does anyone has another idea ?

Comment: Maybe Dart behaves just as Java in this situation : https://stackoverflow.com/a/28165338/5446285

Comment: `List.from` (or `List.of`, etc.) creates a *shallow* copy.  It creates a new `List` with references to the same objects that the original `List` referred to.  If you want them to be completely independent, you will need to create a *deep* copy.  There is no built-in way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

As [jamesdlin says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73832388/dart-for-loop-is-changing-elements-of-my-list-even-when-it-is-cloned#comment130371461_73832388), using `List.from` or the spread operator just creates a shallow copy of the list. Dart does not have a built-in deep copy function that I could find, but if you'll only be working with nested lists like this we can define our own pretty easily:

```
List<T> deepCopy<T>(List<T> list) =>
    list.map((e) => e is List ? deepCopy(e) : e).cast<T>().toList();
```

[Here's a dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=38325d7031a56e037517b6691b14535f) showing the result.